# Codenameone validator not highlighting required fields

Tags: codenameone

I have a simple form that performs validation of each field. For some reason, I think related to the CodenameOne theme, I do not get a red outline or background for fields failing validation, and I do not see the error messages. The form will gray out the "Submit" button until all validations pass, so this part is working. I just can't see the errors on the screen. I have included my form code below. Is this happening because the default theme I am using does not have the required UUIDs to display the error styles?

Is there a way to debug when styles are being applied but are not available in the theme?

```
   Form registrationForm = new Form("My Registration");
    BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
    bl.setCenterBehavior(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER);
    registrationForm.setLayout(bl);
    registrationForm.setFormBottomPaddingEditingMode(true);
    ComponentGroup cg = new ComponentGroup();
    final TextField nicknameField = new TextField("", "Screen name (publicly viewable)", 25, TextArea.ANY);
    cg.addComponent(nicknameField);
    final TextField emailField = new TextField("", "Email address", 40, TextArea.EMAILADDR);
    cg.addComponent(emailField);
    final TextField passwordField = new TextField("", "Password", 40, TextArea.PASSWORD);
    cg.addComponent(passwordField);
    final TextField passwordConfirmField = new TextField("", "Type your password again", 40, TextArea.PASSWORD);
    cg.addComponent(passwordConfirmField);
    final TextField sloganField = new TextField("", "Slogan (publicly viewable), ex: Go Hokies!", 30, TextArea.ANY);
    cg.addComponent(sloganField);

    Button submit = new Button("Submit");
    Validator v = new Validator();

    v.addConstraint(nicknameField, new LengthConstraint(3));
    v.addConstraint(emailField, RegexConstraint.validEmail("You must enter a valid email address to receive confirmation"));
    v.addConstraint(passwordField, new LengthConstraint(8));
    v.addConstraint(passwordConfirmField, new LengthConstraint(8));
    v.addSubmitButtons(submit);
    submit.addActionListener((e) -> {
        String password = passwordField.getText();
        String passwordConfirm = passwordConfirmField.getText();
        if (!password.equals(passwordConfirm)) {
            Dialog.show("Password error", "The password and password confirmation did not match. Please retype them.", "OK", null);
        } else {
            showConfirmation();
        }
    });   
    cg.addComponent(submit);
    registrationForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cg);
    registrationForm.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error mode sets the UIID to existing UIID with the word "Invalid" appended to it. So a `TextField` will become `TextFieldInvalid`.

In the simulator open the Component Inspector tool and traverse the components to see the UIID's that they have. This will allow you to customize the right UIID's in selected/unselected states.

To enable error message display use `setShowErrorMessageForFocusedComponent(true)`.